# AWS - Install EB CLI on Windows

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to install the elastic beanstalk CLI on an EC2 instance (running AMI) I am installing EB CLI on Windows,

```
C:\windows\system32>pip install awsebcli
Collecting awsebcli
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(1006
1, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',
 None, 10061, None))': /simple/awsebcli/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(1006
1, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',
 None, 10061, None))': /simple/awsebcli/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(1006
1, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',
 None, 10061, None))': /simple/awsebcli/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(1006
1, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',
 None, 10061, None))': /simple/awsebcli/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(1006
1, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',
 None, 10061, None))': /simple/awsebcli/
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(1006
1, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',
 None, 10061, None))': /simple/awsebcli/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(1006
1, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',
 None, 10061, None))': /simple/awsebcli/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(1006
1, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',
 None, 10061, None))': /simple/awsebcli/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(1006
1, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',
 None, 10061, None))': /simple/awsebcli/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(1006
1, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',
 None, 10061, None))': /simple/awsebcli/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement awsebcli
  No distributions at all found for awsebcli
```

But I can't. I guess Its a proxy problem bit I don't know how to solve it